# MS Access "ORDER BY" Sorting Algorithm

Tags: ms-access, sorting, comparison

Good people,

I have observed that the MS Access ORDER BY clause sorts records in non-ASCII way. This is different from MySQL - which is generally ASCII-compliant. Let me give you a little background so you understand why this is a problem to me.

Back in 2010, I wrote a generic database transaction logger. The goal was to detect changes occurring on (theoretically) any SQL database and log them in another database. To do this, I use a shadow MySQL database where I maintain a copy of the entire source database. The shadow database is designed using the EAV model so that it is agnostic to the source database schema.

Every once in a while, I read out of both the source and shadow databases, order the records based on their primary keys and format the records to correspond one-to-one. Then, I do a full database compare using a merge algorithm.

This solution has worked okay until last week when a user set it up against an Access database with string primary keys which are not always alphanumeric. All of a sudden the software started logging ghost transactions that have not happened on the source database.

On closer examination, I found out that MS Access orders non-alphanumeric characters in a fashion different from MySQL. As such, my merge algorithm, which assumes similar sort order for both source and shadow records, started to fail.

Now, I have figured out a way I could tweak my software to "cure" such primary keys before using them but it would help a great deal if I know precisely what is the nature of MS Access' ordering scheme. Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

PS: Let me know if there's anything I need to clarify. I am trying to avoid typing too much of what may not be useful.

Comment: Are your values for "string primary key" always the same length?

Comment: I asked because of this article (also linked below in my answer):
http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=120275

Answer (score 0):

I had a difficult time with this a few years ago.  I'm sorry I didn't retain the solution, but it used VBA and it was not concise or elegant.

I opened the tables as DAO recordsets, advanced through the records, and used the `strcomp()` function to compare keys.  I experimented a lot with the binary/text option of `strcomp()` and I believe it was finally necessary to insert an error-handling component!

This [discussion](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?p=1115544) may be relevant.  Also [this](http://www.bigresource.com/VB-How-to-sort-alphanumeric-field-in-access-database--4V5syuZv4B.html) and [this](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=120275).

Comment: I saw a VBA solution on the MSDN but didn't like it much either mostly because I am not allowed to alter the Access database. I considered using the ASC function in Access and the corresponding ASCII function in MySQL and ordering by that but those only get you the ASCII number of the first character. That's not reliable because there are cases where the first character is the same across different values. Now, is there any hash function available in Access? My research so far has turned up no results. With such a function I could order the results by the hash code instead.

Comment: The hash idea sounds good.  But your knowledge and research are already beyond what I can provide.  I wonder if you can use the VBA solution -- via links to an external Access database.

Comment: Thanks just the same, Smandoli. It's very frustrating that MS Access doesn't support things like MD5 hash or converting strings to hex out of the box. You know, I am dealing with a very unique situation here. My application works with most other databases seamlessly and even with Access, it only becomes a problem when the primary key of the table in question contains all sorts of special characters. That's not a problem one wants to spend a lot of time on, but sometimes it happens that one has to. I'll report back here once I find an appropriate solution.